# Can I remove existing fields or add some more fields in the default User DB in Django?, Also can i login using email instead of username?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-database

I want to create a database for my project using the default Django database 'user' and I found that Django has a primary key username and some fields are not required, if I can add more fields to the existing DB 'user' that would be great...

I want to log in using email instead of username and change some fields to required. Also, can I add a field 'address and 'mobile'?

Iam using Django 3.5.2

I have tried adding new fields using the following but still couldn't find a way to change the primary key and required fields

**forms.py ->**

```
class CustomerUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User #django default model
        fields=['first_name','last_name','password','email','username']
        widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput()
        }
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= models.CRegistration
        fields=['address','mobile','profile_pic']
```

**models.py ->**

```
class CRegistration(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pic/CustomerProfilePic/', null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20) #null=True
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can customise user table in django. Also you can authenticate with email

Here is the below link, this article explains exactly what you need. Refer the django documentation for more

[Django custom user with email authentication](https://medium.com/@royprins/django-custom-user-model-email-authentication-d3e89d36210f)